# Unable to repaint waterfall chart in D3js with Angular

Tags: d3.js

I have created an Angular directive for waterfall chart in D3, and want to update the chart as soon as values get updated. I've put the scope.$watch and I can see the new data coming to the directive. But the paintChart() function which I am creating to re-render the chart with new data does not seem to work correctly.

Even if I am able to receive different arrays of data, I am not able to re-paint the chart with different data. I tried to put chart and bar variable definitions out of the paint method and re-use them again with different parameters, but no success. Like if I put the following code out of the paintChart() function:

```
var chart = d3.select(rawSvg[0])
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

The function stops working.

[Here is the Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/8a958m7j/). The data is changing perfectly on selction, but I am struggling to get the chart re-painted properly on changing data.

**UPDATE:** I put the following code as first lines in paintChart() function, to remove previous SVG and it's associated elements before creating chart:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

Now the chart is successfully updating when different data is selected. But there are more issues:

1. When I select different data to update the chart, and re-select previously selected data, The last column of waterfall Chart disappears and shows NaN. The last column shows no error when loaded at first time. Only when data is toggled, this error occurs. You can reproduce this error by selecting different data from select-box and then re-selecting previously selected data. This seems a very strange issue.
2. It doesn't seem to me a correct way to remove SVG and it's associated groups/elements and render a totally new chart every time new data comes.